# Superfish plugin tweak - adding a 'current' class to a parent li element too

Tags: jquery, traversal, superfish

I'm building a site with some software that spits out a set of hierarchically nested lists that I'm in turn using the superfish jquery plugin to turn into drop-down menus.

The issue that I have is that said software will only apply one active class (to whichever page/element is active at the time) - if I'm on a second-level page and I need to apply one to the parent

tag as well, in order for the menus to stay open. I don't want to hack the core for obvious reasons, so I'm wondering if I can use Jquery to apply some simple magic.

Is there a way of targetting the parent li element of a list that contains a class='active'?  (and not if I'm only in a top-level page, so don't need to traverse upwards)

For example the code that the software generates is like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">First level</a>
     <ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Second 1</li>
         <li><a href="#">Second 2</li>
         <li><a href="#">Second 3</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I need to apply another class="active" to the top-level `<li>` as well because it's the parent of the active node.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var $this;
$("ul > li").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);

    if($this.find("> li.active").length)
      $this.addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - after a little tweak and it worked beautifully. I run this after I invoke the superfish js and the tab highlights. Thank you so much.